# Value of different data types return TRUE on equality

Tags: r

I have a trivial question for which I'm unable to find the right explanation.

I'm exploring the operators' concept in R and puzzled to see the below output. How can a class of character and numeric value return TRUE on equality?

```
> "100" == 100

[1] TRUE

> a = "34"

> b = 34

> a == b

[1] TRUE

> class(a)

[1] "character"

> class(b)

[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: If they are of different type, one is coerced to the type of the other. There is a hierarchy which I don't remember

Comment: You’ve stumbled upon a very unfortunate property of R. Implicit coercion is ubiquitous and often leads to subtle bugs.

Comment: If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw.